# How do i get excel to recognize < signs as a number to return to lowest value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a set of results that have <0.001, <20 etc. I am trying to take the Min and then also the Max of a column of numbers EG. <0.01 <20 etc. When taking the Min or Max, excel doesn't recognize the < symbol.  What formula would either recognise the < symbol or alter this all in just one formula? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data start in A2, this to remove the < and convert to a number:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"<",""))
```

Then take the MIN of the resulting column.

If you are using Excel 365 and have access to dynamic arrays, you can do it in one shot. Edit the range length appropriately.

```
=MIN(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A1000,"<","")))
```

Comment: You'd be able to shorten this to: `=MIN(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A1000,"<","")))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
=MAX(--MID(A1:A1000,2,99))
```

And

```
=MIN(--MID(A1:A1000,2,99))
```

Depending on the version of Excel you'd need to enter through pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>